# Unable to resolve module `component-bind` from `node_modules\socket.io-client\build\manager.js`: component-bind could not be found within the project

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json from my React-native project and did npm install and react-native run-android.
After build successfull it gave me this error

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `component-bind` from `node_modules\socket.io-client\build\manager.js`: component-bind could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\Double Projects\New\BlaBlaSixth\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\Double Projects\New\BlaBlaSixth\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\Double Projects\New\BlaBlaSixth\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at Object.resolve (D:\Double Projects\New\BlaBlaSixth\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at D:\Double Projects\New\BlaBlaSixth\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (D:\Double Projects\New\BlaBlaSixth\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
    at D:\Double Projects\New\BlaBlaSixth\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\Double Projects\New\BlaBlaSixth\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

I installed the latest version of socket.io-client but still the error didn't solved.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try reinstalling the whole dependencies directory. If a major dependency is somehow changed in your repository, it could cause issues. Run the command in the main project directory where you see the node_modules folder to remove and install them again.

`rm -rf node_modules && npm i`

If this doesn’t work, you can try following the steps outlined in the error message. Here is a slightly modified command ready to copy to your terminal:

`watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && npm i`

This will clear watchman watches, reset the metro bundler cache, remove the haste cache, reinstall the whole node_modules directory, and clear the yarn cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- rm -rf node_modules && yarn install (or npm)
- clear the caches
- close the package manager
- In android Studio invalidate caches and close
- Restart Android studio and simulator (or phone)
- Try to start yarn android again (react-native start-android)

Please also make sure 'component-bind' exists in socket-io